# Recommendations for a really good DVB-T card for linux

Tags: linux, streaming, tuner-card, mythtv

I am so fed up with my Sony HDR that is already obsolete. As I am a linux geek, I have been thinking on building my own media central.

Reading various hardware support list gives some information about if a card works or not, but not if its good.  Also, I would like to buy a card from a vendor that actively supports linux.

Can someone recommend a really good DVB-T card?

I would need:

- Good linux support. DVB-T support.
- Radio as an option.
- Two or more
  channels, three seems like the
  maximum that I would ever need, but who knows...
  Doesn't matter if its one or two cards, as long as it works.
- CAM support. Additional card or built in.  I have no idea of how this works actually, but I think the CA module must support mpeg4 too?
- HDTV/Mpeg4 support (Software is fine, I guess.)

I would also need a good remote control (bluetooth) that not neccesarily needs to come with the card, and a decent fanless graphics card that handles hdtv on linux...

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is the [Hauppauge WinTV-HVR-2200](http://www.hauppauge.co.uk/site/products/data%5Fhvr2200mc.html). A [linux driver](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge_WinTV-HVR-2200) has recently been developed (though it only supports the digital tuners at present).

It's a *really* nice card - dual tuner, support for HD, MPEG capture and it gives us a perfect signal on all UK free-to-air DVB-T channels where other cards have struggled finding more than two or three multiplexes.

Take a look to see if does all the stuff you want, but I can't recommend it enough. It's also relatively cheap for a dual tuner card.

---

Edit: I should mention that I've only been using it under Windows so under Linux YMMV, but the LinuxTV drivers are normally very trustworthy.

Comment: Beat me, with a much better answer, +1 for Hauppauge - they work well on Linux despite half the products having "win" in their name.